# Reference a for loop value when finding the average of data

Tags: r, for-loop, row, average, tibble

I have a dataframe on crop yields called wwdata that looks a bit like this:

```
Year Region       Yield
2009 northeast    9.1
2009 northwest    8
2009 yorkshire    7.8
2009 eastmidlands 8.1
2009 westmidlands 7.9
...
```

The data continues for about 100 lines and goes from 2009 to 2018.

I want to try and find the average yield of this crop for each year using a for loop and add it to the bottom of the dataframe using tibble so that I can plot it on a ggplot. This is the code I am trying to use:

```
x <- seq(2009,2018,1)
for (val in x) {
  y <-  wwdata[wwdata$Year == x]
  average_x <- mean(y$yield)
  wwdata <- add_row(Year = x, Region = "Average", Yield = average_x ) 
}
```

This usually works in other languages but in R it doesn't seem to understand that the "x" is the current for loop value. Error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(wwdata, wwdata$Year == z) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I'm not sure if there is a specific syntax I don't know, any help is appreciated!

Comment: `val` is the current for loop value not `x`.

Comment: `aggregate(Yield ~ Year, data=wwdata, FUN=mean)`

Comment: We don't use `for` loops for this task in R. We have functions like `aggregate` for this (and many even more efficient alternatives in contributed packages).

Answer (score 0):

```
    library(magrittr)

    Z  = lapply(2009:2018, function(x){
            data.frame(Year = x, 
            Region = "Average",
            wdata$Yield[ wdata$year == x ] %>% mean)
         })%>% do.call(what = "rbind")
```

Then we can bind it by row:

```
rbind(wdata, Z)
```